# How to sync Algolia data in frontend after posting a new data

Tags: algolia

Now I'm developing using Algolia, Firestore and CloudFunctions.

Every posting a new data in Firestore, cloud functions triggered to async Algolia's index.
But no idea of how to get the new data  in Frontend after posting it.
I mean Frontend doesn't subscribe Algolia's index.
After posting a new data, should the frontend be reloaded using API?

I thought there is a function like snapshot listener in Algolia, unfortunately there is not.
How to achieve the goal?

Comment: i think one way is to have a refresh button to handle these asynchronous scenarios. a lot of sites have these refresh buttons